# Uniform convergence on [a, b] of series of continuous functions implies that series is continuous on (0, b]

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-convergence

(1) Let's say we have a series $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ which converges uniformly on every closed interval $[a, b]$ where $a > 0$ is arbitrary and $b$ is fixed. Moreover $f_n$ is continuous for every $n$. Does this imply that $f$ is continuous on $(0, b]$?

I know that uniformly convergent series of continuous functions is continuous. But answers to this questions:

[Continuity and differentiability of function series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130870/continuity-and-differentiability-of-function-series) 
[Continuity of series sumfunction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716354/continuity-of-series-sumfunction)

imply that continuity on $[a, b]$ implies continuity on $(0, b]$ even if series is not uniformly convergent on $(0, b]$. The second question even provided a proof but I am not convinced by it. Because this sequence:

$$f_n(x) = \frac{\sin{nx}}{nx}\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$

seems to be uniformly convergent on $[a, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ but not on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$. But if I do analogous proof to the one in answer for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716354/continuity-of-series-sumfunction) question (but for uniform convergence instead of continuity) it shows that this sequence should be uniformly convergent on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

Could someone explain to me if (1) is true and if that's the case why proof from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716354/continuity-of-series-sumfunction) can't be extended to uniform convergence, please?

Comment: Uniform convergence is a global notion whereas continuity is a local notion. That's why. The continuity of the $f_n$ and uniform convergence on $[a,b]$ for $0<a<b$ ensures that the restriction of $f$ to $[a,b]$ is continuous. Given $x_0 \in (0,b]$, you can find $a$ such that $0<a<x_0$, so the continuity of $f$ at $x_0$ follows.

Comment: Thank you. That's a nice explanation